# Android Redirection to Browser for Payment

Tags: android, browser, android-activity, callback, payment

I want to develop an eshop android application that supports credit card payment through browser redirection.

In checkout Activity, when the user press the 'checkout' button, the browser should be started and redirect the user to the bank's payment page. After the user's credit card charge the browser's activity should be finished and returns the transaction id to the checkout activity:

Checkout Activity -> Bank's page (Browser) -> Checkout Activity.

Is this possible?